# Number of loops of a ball bouncing in a room with obstacles

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, geometry, number-theory, intuition

### Introduction

With a friend of mine we were studying the following problem: given a $m\times n$ grid draw this pattern (I don't know how to describe it in words)

[image] [image]

The first image has $3$ loops and the second image has only $1$ loop.

**The question is:** is it possible to know the number of loops ($=l$) in advance by knowing the size of the grid?
The answer is yes and simply the answer is:

> $$l=\gcd(m,n)$$

---

### Question

After finding this result we complicated the problem:
*Is it possible to know the number of loops if there are holes in the grid?*

We noticed that if you have an $n\times n$ grid and you remove the corner the number of loops is $n-1$, but in general we did not notice a pattern for a generic situation.

But we have made these observations:

1. The location of the holes affects the result
2. The number of loops is invariant for rotations and symmetries
3. The presence of a hole can increase or decrease the number of loops.

Here is an example of why rule $1$ applies:
[image]
Here the first graph has $2$ loops and the second graph has $1$ loop (in both cases you have a $3\times 3$ grid with only $1$ hole)

Here is an example of why rule $3$ applies:
[image]
[image]
In the first case there is one less loop compared to the $3\times3$ scheme (the image is above), in the second image instead there is one more loop

**In general however we wanted to consider any grid with any number of holes in any position**

---

### My idea

My idea was to consider a binary matrix in which
$$(a)_{ij}=\begin{cases}1&\text{There is }\textbf{not}\text{ an hole}\\0&\text{There is an hole}\end{cases}$$
This consideration is useful because hypothetically I could consider any grid as a larger grid where the rest it's empty

Obviously this problem can also be seen as:

1. A bouncing ball in a room with obastacles.
2. A laser reflected in a room of mirrors

The purpose of the problem however is to know how many loops there are given a given grid.

### Update

I don't know if it can be useful, but in knot theory there are these two formulas:

Given an adjacency matrix $\mathbf{A}$, let $E$ the set of the edges in the graph and $T$ the set of the triangles in the graph.

$$\text{trace}(\mathbf{A}^2)=2\cdot|E|$$
$$\text{trace}(\mathbf{A}^3)=6\cdot|T|$$

Maybe there is a similar relationship for this case.

Comment: Obviously the braiding is not terribly relevant.  The only thing is that each path reflects off edges at the midpoint... Oh I like this.  Okay one thing I thought of: an ear doesn't count, the P pentomino is exactly like the 2x2 square with slightly less bounce in that one direction. If a single length 1 edge cuts the object into two pieces then the shape can be simplified.

Comment: @DanUznanski Yup, the problem can be seen from multiple points of view, this was the most fascinating one from a graphic point of view ahaha